# Why static member load first in memory

Tags: c#, oop

I have used static class and static members many times in c# application but I did think much more on its internal, yesterday some one asked me why static members load first in memory ?

Is it right question ? if yes then please explain me why it is.

Thanks,

Comment: Here's a good read: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15269/Static-Keyword-Demystified

Comment: Static members exist till the [Application Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173138(v=vs.80).aspx) remains loaded.

Comment: an interview question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static class is initialized when the class is loaded. It is initialized before any objects are created. Because it does not need any objects to be initialized. There can be any number of static classes and static fields. They all are initialized first and once so that they can be used anywhere and anytime.

Hope the explanation helps.

Answer (score 3):

Static, or rather class fields, are stored within the class itself and doesn't require an instance of the class to be accessed. The class is loaded into memory as soon as it's first used and as soon as the class is loaded, the class fields are available.

Answer (score 2):

A static member is a member that is allocated at run-time, and it's memory addressing is immutable. What I mean be that is once the static member is initialized it stays in the same place in memory until the end of the program.

That being said, static members are initialized at run-time, but not necesarily the first things initialized. To explain further, depending on your application structure, things such as compile time constant strings and other constants can be allocated "first", meaning at the very beginning of the memory addressing of the application.

A very good feature of this is the fact that speed is greatly increased, because there is no need to "search" memory for the correct member/method to call on.